# How to mark a test run with a non-TFS build, possibly as comment?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, test-plan

I want to track results of manual test cases in VS online (where I keep my tasks, bugs etc). I've created a test plan and some test cases, and can start a test run and mark test cases as passed/failed, with comments per test case.

However, my source control and build are not in VS online, but in a totally separate system - non-ideal situation I can't change. I would like to mark each test run with a build number from my build system - but how can I do that?

I've tried:

**Run with options - but that only lets me select TFS builds, and my build is not in TFS.**
[image: Run test plan with options - select build]

**Add build as test run comment - but how do I enter a comment?**
[image: test results - comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support to use a build outside VSTS. It only supports to choose a TFS build. You could vote this User Voice about choosing an outside build: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16363333-vsts-choosing-a-outsite-build-when-run-a-test-case

About the Test Run comments, in VSTS web page, it can't add a comment for test runs. But you could use **MTM** to add a Test Run comment.

1. Open MTM and connect to your test plan.
2. Under the **Test** tab, choose **Analysis Test Runs**.
3. Find your test run and double click to open that test run.
4. Add your comment and Save.

Comment: Works great, I also voted for the user comment. I must say that test plan tracking in VSTS is extremely limited, and this weird UI limitation is not helping at all.